# django annotate related fields at once with Count()

Tags: python, django, annotate

My `Profile` model have two m2m fields in one model - `region` and `country`. And as you know, `country` has there own `region` with foreignkey.

I want to try counting profiles per region - not only include `region` but also in `country__region`.

i.e.) If some have only has `Africa` region, and other has only `Congo` country (with the region `Africa`), I want to filter them at one.

I try to solve it using `annotate`. I can find count of region individually like below

```
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    region_count = profiles.values('region').annotate(region_count=Count('region'))
    country_count = profiles.values('region').annotate(region_count=Count('country__region'))
```

But how can I count queryset with specific region, filtering with `region` and `region__country` at once? Is there any possible method?

Here's my profile / country model. The region model just has name field.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    region = models.ManyToManyField(
        Region,
        verbose_name="Region(s) of interest",
        blank=True,
    )
    country = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country,
        related_name="country",
        verbose_name="Countries of interest",
        blank=True,
    )
    ...

class Country(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    ...
```

Thanks for any help.

### Summary

I want to count queryset with `region` and `country__region` at once with `annotate`.

Comment: what version django do you use?

Comment: is this works ? ( I don't really understand your problem ) `region_count = profiles.values('region').annotate(Count('region'), Count('country__region')).distinct()`

Comment: @BearBrown I use 1.11

Comment: @AlexisdeCorbier That can't merge `region` and `country__region`. My problem detail - I want to get all profiles including `region` or `country__region` per region. i.e.) `africa` - profiles having africa `region` and having africa in `country__region` both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use [conditional-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) before count:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Count

Profile.objects.annotate(
    reg=Case(
        When(region__isnull=True, then=F('country__region')),
        default=F('region'))
    ).values('reg').annotate(region_count=Count('reg'))
```

Comment: @seuling does it help you, or i wrong in understand your question.

Comment: I tried your answer, and it's good to know `Case` and `When`. Unfortunately, I guess it's not what I want to find. If use conditional expressions, one profile object is counted just one time. For example, if someone has `Africa` region and `South Korea` country, he/she should be counted in both `Africa` and `Asia`. But in case-when scenario, it's only counted for `Africa`.

Comment: Anyway, really thanks for your helpful answer. I'm trying to select query with conditional expression